# Application update?

Tags: android

I have build a maps related software which require the app to get update whenever the base map is modified. Basically we have nodes.json whose data will get updated under such situation.

One way i am thinking of is to have the latest version of .apk on my dropbox account. Whenever the file in my account is of higher version than the one currently installed, user will get a pop-up . But i am not very clear about the implementation.
Also the application works offline so whenever user connects to some internet source he should be notified..
Please help me with my solution or suggest if there is a better solution.

thanks

Comment: do you have to update the entire app? why not read the most updated data from a backend?

Comment: not necessarily the entire app but the file from which it is taking the node point values(lat/long).The app works offline so the data has to be stored locally

Comment: so store the data in a local file and update it whenever there's network connectivity.  no need to update the entire app for this.